# Package in dl4j does not exist

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, package, cannot-find-symbol

I'm trying to start the dl4j examples in IntelliJ using the 1.8 Java 64x JDK.

I've followed the instructions exactly like in [description](https://deeplearning4j.org/quickstart)

Now the last step doesn't work. While starting i get hundreds of exception like:

```
 Error:(3,35) java:package org.deeplearning4j.berkeley does not exist
```

or

```
Error:(19,38) java:cannot find symbol symbol: class BaseLayer
```

So I guess the problem has something to do with the import of the package. I need to add that I'm new to IntelliJ. Do i need to consider something special about it?
Is it possible that I need to rebuild the pom.xml for Maven because of using Java 8?

Thanks for any ideas!

P.s. `maven clean install` (Version: 3.16.0-4-amd64) throws some exceptions:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.deeplearning4j:dl4j-examples:jar:0.7-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin is missing. @ org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-examples-parent:0.7-SNAPSHOT, /home/usr/own installations/idea-IC-163.10154.41/dl4j-examples/pom.xml, line 44, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.deeplearning4j:dl4j-spark:jar:0.7-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin is missing. @ org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-examples-parent:0.7-SNAPSHOT, /home/usr/own installations/idea-IC-163.10154.41/dl4j-examples/pom.xml, line 44, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.deeplearning4j:dl4j-spark-examples:pom:0.7-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin is missing. @ org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-examples-parent:0.7-SNAPSHOT, /home/usr/own installations/idea-IC-163.10154.41/dl4j-examples/pom.xml, line 44, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.deeplearning4j:datavec-examples:jar:0.7-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin is missing. @ org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-examples-parent:0.7-SNAPSHOT, /home/usr/own installations/idea-IC-163.10154.41/dl4j-examples/pom.xml, line 44, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.deeplearning4j:dl4j-cuda-specific-examples:jar:0.7-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin is missing. @ org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-examples-parent:0.7-SNAPSHOT, /home/usr/own installations/idea-IC-163.10154.41/dl4j-examples/pom.xml, line 44, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.deeplearning4j:nd4j-examples:jar:0.7-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin is missing. @ org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-examples-parent:0.7-SNAPSHOT, /home/usr/own installations/idea-IC-163.10154.41/dl4j-examples/pom.xml, line 44, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.deeplearning4j:rl4j-examples:jar:0.7-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 147, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin is missing. @ org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-examples-parent:0.7-SNAPSHOT, /home/usr/own installations/idea-IC-163.10154.41/dl4j-examples/pom.xml, line 44, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.deeplearning4j:arbiter-examples:jar:0.7-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin is missing. @ org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-examples-parent:0.7-SNAPSHOT, /home/usr/own installations/idea-IC-163.10154.41/dl4j-examples/pom.xml, line 44, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-examples-parent:pom:0.7-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin is missing. @ line 44, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] DeepLearning4j Examples Parent
[INFO] DeepLearning4j Examples
[INFO] dl4j-spark-examples
[INFO] dl4j-spark
[INFO] datavec-examples
[INFO] DeepLearning4j CUDA special examples
[INFO] nd4j-examples
[INFO] Reinforcement Learning4j Examples
[INFO] arbiter-examples
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building DeepLearning4j Examples Parent 0.7-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ deeplearning4j-examples-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-default) @ deeplearning4j-examples-parent ---
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion failed with message:
********** Minimum Maven Version is 3.3.1. Please upgrade Maven before continuing (run "mvn --version" to check). **********
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] DeepLearning4j Examples Parent .................... FAILURE [0.902s]
[INFO] DeepLearning4j Examples ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] dl4j-spark-examples ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] dl4j-spark ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] datavec-examples .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] DeepLearning4j CUDA special examples .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] nd4j-examples ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Reinforcement Learning4j Examples ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] arbiter-examples .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.137s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 05 17:13:18 CET 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/118M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-default) on project deeplearning4j-examples-parent: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: what do you mean by last step? Using DL4J In Your Own Projects: Configuring the POM.xml File ?

Comment: starting examples. run project..

Comment: I tested the project and it worked for me. Make sure you the "mvn clean install" command is successful before importing to intellij and that you are importing it as a maven project.

Comment: I do have some error using "mvn clean install" statement. [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-default) on project deeplearning4j-examples-parent: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]

Comment: did you "Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed"? Please add last blocks of maven command output to your post as well as maven version.

Comment: yes and yes I do, somehow it has problems building the pom file i think...

Comment: ********** Minimum Maven Version is 3.3.1. Please upgrade Maven before continuing (run "mvn --version" to check). **********

-> please get the last apache maven version and try again (mine is 3.3.9)

Comment: My maven version is 3.16.0-4. That's newer than 3.3.1!

Comment: I think that  3.16.0-4 is your kernel image version. The maven version is displayed in the first line output by the command: mvn --version

Comment: updated, still doesn't work

Comment: what is the new error message?

Comment: same error message

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little late, but I had the same error...

For me it was that the JAVA_HOME variable was set to the JRE and not to the JDK.
so set the JAVA_HOME variable to something like this: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112 (of course the version am vary)

Otherwise there is the Link for Help 1: http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
There are also some common examples why it might fail...